# case statement without always

Tags: verilog

Can I have a case statement without a always block like an inline if condition does not need a always function?

```
assign WORD_OUT = (SELECT_BIT_IN) ? WORD_IN1 : WORD_IN2;
```

but if I try this,

```
assign WORD_OUT = case (SELECT_BIT_IN)
    4'd0 : WORD_IN0;
    4'd1 : WORD_IN1;
```

or this

```
case (SELECT_BIT_IN)
    1'd0 : assign WORD_OUT = WORD_IN0;
    1'd1 : assign WORD_OUT = WORD_IN1;
```

It gives me an error.

I am trying to avoid using any registers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. A case statement should always be in an `always` or `initial` block.

You have two choices if you don't want to use ternary conditionals. The first is use an always block which doesn't have edge sensitivity as shown below. This does **not** infer registers (that's not what declare the signal of `reg` type means), it infers a multiplexer with constant assignment - as there is no clock, so there is no register, the `*` simply means any input change.

```
reg WORD_OUT;

always @ * begin
    case (SELECT_BIT_IN)
    ...
    WORD_OUT = WORD_IN0;
    ...
    endcase
end
```

Alternatively specifically infer a ROM or multiplexer depending on what your input signals are (possibly instantiate a module of one). If the inputs are constants (like parameters), then your case simply infers a ROM. If the inputs are nets, then your code infers a multiplexer.

Comment: Yes. It's an easy trip-up that the `reg` keyword just means storage; it *doesn't* mean that a register is required. The above answer will synthesize into logic. Remember your `default` case, though!